# NiFi User related information in Flow

Tags: apache-nifi

I have enabled AD authentication in my NiFi cluster. Now I want track the activities of users like (Which user has triggered a particular flow). Is there any possible way to do this?

How can I pass logged in username as a attribute in a flow?

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components in the flow purposely cannot access user information since they are running independent of any user.

User actions are already tracked by NiFi itself, if you go to the hamburger menu in the top-right and select Flow Configuration History you will see every change to the flow and which user made it.

Comment: Thanks Bryan!! This is really useful. by any chance can we get "Flow Configuration History "in flow file?

Comment: The processor API purposely does not expose this, but there are two ways you could get it.. a custom ReportingTask has access to these events, alternatively you could use HTTP processors to query the REST API to make the same calls the UI is making